# Check if the datetime field is passed the current timestamp

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, php

I have a content type which has a required field named field_deadline.
How do I check if field_deadline of nodes of this content type is greater than current timestamp (deadline has not been met yet)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (strtotime($node->field_deadline['und'][0]['value']) > time()) {
  // deadline has not been met yet.
}
```

Comment: ... and typing code in an html text area owns me again :) ... fix it. you're welcome.